# Returning data from didReceiveData to the calling object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a class (Ntwk) that I want to use for network communication. This class will handle all network I/O. But with asynchronous I/O I have to declare the didReceivData delegate in Ntwk, which totally spoils my the data flow. Here's is why -

The ViewController is creating a Ntwk object and calling the PostData function in it and returns immediately. So now how does the ViewController get the data from the call? This must be a solved problem and obj-c probably already provides a way to do this but I am completely lost. I am learning this as I go, so I am looking for help.

I see two ways to solve this -

1. Have the didReceiveData delegate somehow be defined and called in the ViewController. This will be awesome.
2. Pass either a block or a function pointer to the Ntwk object from the ViewController and have it called from inside the didReceiveData delegate inside the Ntwk object.

Is it possible to do either one of these?

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about "correct" - that seems meaningless. But I think 2 is better, and yes it is certainly possible. Here's my example of how to do it: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m Notice how we are passed a completion handler when we are called, and we call it when we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The approaches you mentioned are pretty much right but if you declare the DidReceiveData method in same class then we can not achieve the MVC and as you created the Network class for the functionality you can use either Block callback reference or you can use Delegate-Protocol methodology, for this you need to set the delegate with self as the reference of the calling class, then when your task gets finished just call the method from Protocol from this delegate reference.
This might solve your problem.

Comment: I am really new to this and don't have any idea how to do this. Are there links from Apple developer documentation that describe how to do this?

Comment: use the below link, it will help you understanding the concept

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html